# Вывод данных из БД в TextBox

Tags: c#, база-данных, textbox

В моей базе данных есть такая таблица.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я динамично создаю TextBox и пытаюсь, в каждом из них разместить тест в с колонки три

```
TextBox name_vacancies = new TextBox();
            while(reader_vacancies.Read()) {
                name_vacancies.Text = reader_vacancies[2].ToString();

            }
```

Но получается так, что текст вставляеть только в первый тестбокс и с последней строчки с БД.
Как реализовать так, чтобы текст выводился в разные текстбоксы

Comment: Надо выделять работу с БД в отдельный класс. Получать из базы коллекцию нужных данных, а потом уже отображать эту коллекцию в UI. Не надо перемешивать работу с БД с работой с контролами.

Comment: Ну потому что вы перезаписываете значение в один и тот же контрол. Учить ООП.